# semantic names for JS constructors/prototypes vs classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, terminology, ecmascript-5

In javascript es6 we have classes where we can do something like this:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  getArea() {
    return this.height * this.width
  }

  static someStaticMethod() {
    // does some utility or something
  }
}
```

Which is roughly just syntactic sugar for the following older es5 code:

```
function Rectangle() {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
}

Rectangle.prototype.getArea = function() {
  return this.height * this.width
}

Rectangle.someStaticMethod = function() {
  // does some utility or something
}
```

In an es6 class it seems simple enough to label the following:

- `Rectangle` is a **class**
- `getArea` is an **instance method**
- `someStaticMethod` is a **class** or **static** **method**

I'm teaching a class on objects prototypes and classes, so I want get the verbiage correct for the above. But additionally...

In the context of es5 JS what are the above classified as? Below is my attempt:

- `Rectangle` is a **constructor function**
- `getArea` is a **prototype method**
- `someStaticMethod`is a **constructor method**

I'm not entire sure if they should be called the same thing in es5 as in es6 or if the names i've given them are entirely accurate.

Comment: Do note that ES7 allows you to define [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) methods directly on the class

Comment: @MatthewHerbst ES7 did change nothing about `static`?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst that's ES6. The only syntax ES7/ES2016 introduced was `**` which was syntactic sugar for `Math.pow()`.

Comment: The term "*instance method*" is sometimes used to distinguish *own* methods (created in the constructor on the instance itself) from prototype methods. But it's still ok to use when you don't talk about that difference. Other options: "normal method", "non-static method", or just "method".

Comment: I'd say that `getArea()` is a prototype method and `getArea = () => {...}` is an instance method. This makes difference i.e. in React where methods are often used as callbacks and needs to have their context bound.

Comment: @marzelin I agree that the distinction can be important, but I would never go as far as calling an arrow function a "method" :-)

Comment: @Bergi an arrow function set in a constructor is bound to an instance. For me it deserves to be called an instance method more than a function set in a prototype since it always be executed in the context of that particular instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names you have given are pretty much accurate, except the last one might be a little bit debatable:

```
Rectangle.someStaticMethod = function() {
  // does some utility or something
}
```

You said:

> `someStaticMethod` is a **constructor method**

You could call it that, or simply a method, but essentially, yes, all of those in your question are correct.

Comment: yeah, that was the one i was definitely most iffy on, if you had to venture you own word before method for the type of method that would be, which might you choose? =D

Comment: @AndrewKim I don't know, maybe `object method`? Or a `literal method`?

Answer (score 1):

> `Rectangle` is a constructor function

Yes, that sounds good. It is a function that constructs new instances, so the description fits.

> `getArea` is a prototype method

A method is a function as a property, and in this case it is indeed part of the prototype.

> `someStaticMethod` is a constructor method

Thats a bit missleading, as it sounds as if it would be a method constructing something. I would rather call it a *method on the constructor*. However I usually call that a "static method" though.

Comment: thanks, the third one was the one i was definitely most uncomfortable about.